# Difference in Difference heterogeneous treatment effect based on scale of pre-post difference

Tags: difference-in-difference, heterogeneity

In a Triple Difference model can we introduce a dummy variable based on scale of difference of dependent variable between pre and post periods? Example: divide both treatment and control groups into 2 sub-groups: one if the difference between pre and post in the dependent variable is say >100 and another if it's <100? The rationale for doing this is that there is some unobserved fundamental difference in treatment effect between these 2 groups but we aren't sure what exactly it is.
I can provide more details if needed.